# C# Parsing text file overhead

Tags: c#, string, parsing, io, split

I'm trying to parse a pretty simple text file into some structures. For that, I need whole text split on every new line and on every whitespace. Code is pretty straightforward:

```
string   path       = "C:/file.ext";
string   fileString = File.ReadAllText (path);
string[] splitFile  = fileString.Split (' ', '\n', '/');
```

After profiling above code (using built-in game engine profiler), I've noticed that while parsing a 40KB file, there is 280KB memory allocated by `File.ReadAllText` and 310KB by string's *Split*, which sums up to almost 15 times the size of a file.

1. Is it normal?
2. Is there any way to read text files while avoiding such big allocations (maybe unsafe code?) ?

NOTE:
The main point is, whether allocations x times bigger than file's size, when reading it, are normal. I understand that reading line by line will let GC collect garbage from previous *ReadLine*. It just doesn't seem normal, and, since target device is an old android phone, I was worried whether parsing 50MB file wouldn't actually make application crash. What I mean by question 2 is how to minimalize allocations, not how to split those allocations.

Comment: You'd have to stream it using FileStream to read line-by-line.

Comment: What about `File.ReadAllLines`?

Comment: You really care about KBs? What device are you using? Also, why don't you use `File.ReadLines` which doesnt need to load the whole file into memory before it can start processing and which also does the line split for you.

Comment: In case of large files a look at `File.ReadLines()` and proceeding the file *line by line*

Comment: @Jeff - Well, I've tried reading line by line, but that way I have to use split on every line. As far as I've tested, this led to even bigger allocations in the end.

FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ - `File.ReadAllLines` also led to bigger allocations, even bigger than reading line by line

TimSchmelter - Target devide is and old android phone, so yes, I really care about memory. In case of a 1.5 MB file parsing allocated about 50 MB, and I want to parse files 50MB+

Comment: Sure you'd split on every line, but since not all lines are managed in memory at the same time, it shouldn't use more memory. Allocation, sure, but it wouldn't hog the memory all at once AFAIK.

Comment: A couple of theories... according to [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) article, strings in .NET use Unicode so if you are loading ascii data from a file, the memory usage could be larger. Also in this article is a formula for figuring out the memory usage of a string. see if that compares to what you are seeing. To re-iterate others points, process the file line by line, and overall you should see less memory usage.

Comment: also keep in mind that the memory usage you are seeing is NOT just from the allocated string, but from leftover objects allocated by the framework for loading and parsing the text for you.

Comment: @Jeremy - yes indeed, calculations match the actual memory usage. I end up with a lot of string after split, many of them very small, and the fact that each string has that base 20 bytes ,no matter the size, pretty much explains everything. I'm still wondering though, if I was to use unsafe code, read char by char (basically what HedrickW suggested), and parse it manually, would I be able to get better performance by not forcing GC to run? What are the chances for my poorly optimized code with low allocation to outperform (by not using GC much) highly optimized .NET code with high allocation?

Comment: You could try the [ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but you have a bunch of extra code to write to parse through the data. Also, what will be the end result of the strings you are reading in? just display? writing to db? Also remember that strings are immutable, so you can't just use 1 variable, because it will unallocate and reallocate on each assignment, causing a bunch of GC-able objects to be created.

Comment: Well, most of the time I don't need strings at all. I use them, because it is a convinient method to deal with text file. In the end 98% of the file ends up being parsed to ints or floats. Well, now that I think of it, using binary reader in that case may be the best solution. The question is, again (under those circumstances), will I get to parse it quicker than just using string `Split` with it's GC flaws? I care about memory, but I also care about speed. If there will be alot of GCing on small allocations, but the method will be faster then manual binary parsing, I'm still going to use it.

Comment: well memory seemed to be your overall concern in the original post. I can only say try it both ways and profile for speed vs memory (which is always our tradeoff, right?!) and choose accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: sorry...one more thing. if you used the [raw filestream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), read byte by byte until you encounter a comma, then [convert the array to int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx), you can reuse memory and it will be pretty fast.

Comment: Thank you very much for the discussion and help. Would you post a short answer for me to mark it? If no, would you mind me accepting Hendrick's answer, since it's pretty much what you've also proposed (I just didn't get it first time) ?

Comment: go right ahead. my ego is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on above post but have you tried reading the file in binary form using the Binary Reader Class then reading in 8 bytes at a time?

Comment: I haven't, but, that sounds like a solution for splitting those allocations. If so, please read edited NOTE at the bottom of my question. I might have misled people with the second question - what I was thinking about is how to minimalize allocations, not how to split them. Correct me if I got you wrong.